# Fit bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on layout container in bootstrap. All of the work of me is working well. But I have fallen a little problem what I cannot solve this. Need your help.

Problem: I have a container, the code is look like this.

```
<div class="container main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebar" data-bind="visible: hideSideNavbar() === true">
            <!--left menu starts here -->
            <div class="span4" id="leftDiv">
                <section id="form_Progress">
                    <!--ko compose: {view: 'formProgress'} -->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </section>
            </div>
            <!--left menu ends here -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            <!--right content starts here -->
            <div class="span8 mainsection">
                <section id="content" class="main container-fluid">
                    <!--ko compose: {model: router.activeItem,
                            afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
                            transition: 'entrance'} -->
                    <!--/ko-->
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the container has two column one is ‘col-md-3’ and other is ‘col-md-9’. The column col-md-3 is hide or show conditionally. If I hide column 'col-md-3' then I want to set width of col-md-9 is 100%. I.e. I want fit the column 100%. Thanks.